# I get the [Error] 'Eintrag' does not name a type and i am not sure why

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, forward-declaration

I have a class "Extendiblehashing" and in it a struct "Bucket" with size_t n,t and an array of B class E objects called values[B].
What I want to achieve is that with the construction of an object of Extendiblehashing I get an array of Bucketpointers (here called Eintrag, should start with only 1 pointer) to a simple Bucket (Bucket is in my case called number1) wich i can later change dynamically to a list of more pointers to more buckets in a method of the class Extendiblehashing.

```
template <typename E, size_t B=7 >
class Extendiblehashing : public Container<E> {

 struct Bucket {
  size_t n; //wieviel ist belegt?
  size_t t; // lokale Tiefe
  E values[B];
  Bucket(): n(0), t(0) {};
  bool member (const E& e) const { for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) if (e==values[i]) return true;
   return false;
   };
  bool append(const E&e) { if (n==B) return false; values[n++]=e; return true;};
 };

 size_t pow(size_t a, size_t b) {size_t u=1; for (int i=0; i<b;++i) u=u*a; return u; };
 size_t d; //globale Tiefe

 Bucket number1();
 Bucket * Eintrag[1];
 Eintrag[0]= &number1;
 size_t n; //Zähler der gespeicherten Elemente

 void sort() const;
public:
 Extendiblehashing( ) : n(0), d(0) {}
 virtual ~Extendiblehashing() {  delete[] Eintrag;}
```

the method that changes the Eintrag array would be something like:

```
 template <typename E, size_t B>
 void Extendiblehashing<E,B>::inc() {
  Bucket * newEintrag = new Bucket[pow(2,d+1)];
  for (int i=0;i<pow(2,d);i++)
   newEintrag[i]=*Eintrag[i];
  for (int i=pow(2,d),j=0;i<pow(2,d+1);i++,j++)
   newEintrag[i]=*Eintrag[j]; 
  d=d+1;
  delete[] Eintrag;
  Eintrag= newEintrag;
  }
```

When compiling I get the error that " 'Eintrag' does not name a type" and hence everything i used Eintrag with does not quite work.
Is there a problem concerning the struct bucket? Or can't I create an array of pointers to just declared Objects?

I'm quite new to programming so pls don't hate me for early mistakes.
Thanks a lot in advance, J.K.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have statements such as

```
Eintrag[0]= &number1;
```

outside of a function. So you need to do that elsewhere, presumably in a constructor.